# Kotlin build cannot get classes created by SquidDatabase

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

In my project I use SquidDatabase almost everywhere to access the database.

I want to transform my project to Kotlin but when I build there are lots of "Unresolved reference: DepartmentInfo" errors.

That `DepartmentInfo` class was created by SquidDatabase while building so I think this problem is caused by Kotlin building before other libraries.

I failed to find any way to change Kotlin to the end of buildlist.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can add a dependency on the SquidDatabase task to the compileKotlin task. I don't know what the SquidDatabase task is, but the syntax would be something like `compileKotlin { dependsOn(squidDatabase) }`. Unless, of course, there is no SquidDatabase task..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted [this issue](https://github.com/yahoo/squidb/issues/278) on Github and got reply from developers.

The solotion is here:

```
build.gradle of your app

 //If using kotlin language,please add this
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

 ......

 dependencies {
     compile 'com.yahoo.squidb:squidb:3.2.3'
     compile 'com.yahoo.squidb:squidb-annotations:3.2.3'
     compile 'com.yahoo.squidb:squidb-android:3.2.3' // For Android projects only
     //annotationProcessor 'com.yahoo.squidb:squidb-processor:3.2.3'
     // If using the android-apt plugin, this becomes
     // apt 'com.yahoo.squidb:squidb-processor:3.2.3'
     // If using kotlin language, this becomes
     kapt 'com.yahoo.squidb:squidb-processor:3.2.3'
 }
```

It may cause errors if you use **DataBinding** for Andriod,and the solution is to add one more `kapt` in your dependencies:

```
kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:$gradle_version'
```